# Advantages of using the export acknowledgement message?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, replication

Could anyone tell me what is the advantages of using the “export acknowledgement message” in replica?

I couldn’t figure out what is the real meaning of using this tool. What is the effect of it if we don’t use it after replica in disconnected environment?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One main point in the documentation for this tool is that it is only applicable in "Disconnected Mode" but the [documentation](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/gp_toolref/data_management_tools/export_acknowledgement_message_data_management_.htm) isn't entirely clear on what that is ([this link](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET_Server_Doc/manager/geodatabase/data_managemen-2136003439/connecte934812630.htm) gives some information). You indicated that you are using this in a disconnected environment so it is probably useful in your case. It could prevent conflicts when the disconnectedness is significant. You have to import change messages when updating the replica and the acknowledgement message confirms that they have been included in the relative replica.

This link explains it the best ... [Export Acknowledgement Message](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/export-acknowledgement-message.htm)

Whether or not it is useful to you is going to depend on how you are using your replica databases. If you are committing edits to a replica and then moving them up into the base, using synchronization etc., it seems like it would be useful or even necessary in that environment. In other words, it would work in a situation where you will [Perform web editing using replicated data from an enterprise geodatabase](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/get-started/windows/tutorial-performing-web-editing-using-replicated-data-from-an-enterprise-geodatabase.htm). If you are just using a replica as a backup, it probably isn't necessary.